# Where do I find the most updated NBA rulebook?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

What is the **official** link of the most updated NBA rulebook?

I connected to a [section](http://www.nba.com/news/nba-register-and-nba-guide) of the NBA website and it does contain a link for the [NBA rulebook](https://mediacentral.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/10/2017-18-NBA-Rule-Book.pdf), but that link redirects to the "Media" seciton of the NBA website, which is reserved for journalists and media covering the NBA.

Is the rulebook accessible only to the media? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the customer service and they gave me [this link](https://ak-static.cms.nba.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/11/Rule-Book-2017-18.pdf) for the 2017/2018 Rulebook. I still don't know how you access the Rulebook from the website.

Answer (score 0):

The Official NBA Guide and NBA Register page is the closest thing to an official link of the most updated NBA rulebook anyone can get: http://www.nba.com/news/nba-register-and-nba-guide

I also tried to access the rulebook and got redirected as well. I don't remember having this happen when I would search for rules in the past. That said, past rules are accessible and available on the NBA officiating page: http://www.nba.com/news/officiating